# pyspark ALS Collaborative Filtering - generating explanation of predictions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

The pyspark ml recommendation package includes an ALS implementation based on the paper by Hu, Koren and Volinsky: http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf for implicit feedback datasets.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-collaborative-filtering.html
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.html

Does the implementation provide a built in function call to generate, for a prediction for a given user and item, p_ui, the linear decomposition into contributing past actions as represented by equation (7) in the HKV article?

I.e. is there a built in way to retrieve the s^u_ij and c_uj matrices of the equation (7)?

Looking over api web docs, I don't see it. Hoping others may have come across it.